# Getting titles from checkboxes when selected to be added to name outputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form and when I have different check boxes for DR., Mr., Mrs., and Miss in my HTML file. How can I make it so if any of those are checked it applies, the appropriate title to the output name, so it is displayed before the `first_name` and `last_name`.

```
<div class="tRow">
    <div class="tCell"><label for="dr">Doctorate?</label></div>
    <div class="tCell"><input type="checkbox" id="dr"></div>
</div><!--ROW STOPS-->
```

---

```
var employee = {
    first_name: first_name,
    last_name: last_name,
};

console.log(employee);

// Create the ouptut as HTML:
var message = employee.first_name + ", " + employee.last_name + "<br>";

// Display the employee object:
output.innerHTML = message;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want radio buttons, but maybe not.

```js
        var first_name = "Bob";
        var last_name = "Dobbs";
        var employee = {
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
        };
        var message = employee.first_name + ", " + employee.last_name;
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');
        var output = document.querySelector('#output');

        for (var ix = 0; ix < checkboxes.length; ix++) {
            checkboxes.item(ix).addEventListener('click', onClick);
        }

        output.innerHTML = message;

        function onClick() {
            var newMessage = message;
            for (var ix = checkboxes.length -1; ix > -1 ; ix--) {

                if (checkboxes.item(ix).checked) {
                    newMessage = checkboxes.item(ix).id + " " + newMessage;
                }
            }
            output.innerHTML = newMessage;
        }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="dr"><span class="label-body">Dr</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="mr"><span class="label-body">Mr</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="mrs"><span class="label-body">Mrs</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="miss"><span class="label-body">Miss</label>
        <div id="output" style="text-transform: capitalize;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is more appropriate to use the *value* attribute for the value rather than the ID.

Comment: Ok. Go ahead and add it. It was simple to use what was already there.

Answer (score 0):

Usually form controls are in a form, which makes life much easier. And where you want users to select one of a few items, either a select or set of radio buttons works best.

E.g.:

```js
function showFullName(el) {

  // Get the parent form from the element that was clicked
  var form = el.form;

  // Get the value of the selected title radio button
  var title = Array.prototype.filter.call(form.title, function(radio){
                return radio.checked;
              })[0].value;

  // Write the full name to the span
  document.getElementById('fullName').textContent = 
    title + ' ' + form.firstName.value + ' ' + form.lastName.value;
}
```

```html
<form id="nameForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First name: 
      <td><input name="firstName">
    <tr>
      <td>Last name: 
      <td><input name="lastName">
    <tr>
      <td>Title: 
      <td><input name="title" type="radio" value="Ms" checked> Ms<br>
          <input name="title" type="radio" value="Mr"> Mr
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Show full name" onclick="showFullName(this);">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span id="fullName"></span>
  </table>
</form>
```

Note that you need a submit button to submit the values.